# Asymmetric behaviour of ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
```

and:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I am writing the ModelSerializer for the Product model:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brand = serializers.UUIDField(source='brand.uuid', default=None)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = ('uuid', 'brand', )
        read_only_fields = ('uuid',)
```

Now going to the shell to serialize / deserialize product objects. First let's deserialize a Product instance:

```
In [1]: product = Product.objects.all().first()

In [2]: ProductSerializer(product)
Out[2]: 
ProductSerializer(<Product: Product object (2)>):
    uuid = UUIDField(read_only=True)
    brand = UUIDField(default=None, source='brand.uuid')

In [3]: ProductSerializer(product)['brand'] 
Out[3]: <BoundField value=1b03c6e1-8d9c-4273-ad07-d0d59a7f8cd9 errors=None>
```

So the field 'brand' is a normal UUID field, as expected. Now in the other way around (serializing):

```
In [4]: data = {'brand': '1b03c6e1-8d9c-4273-ad07-d0d59a7f8cd9', }

In [5]: serializer = ProductSerializer(data=data)

In [6]: serializer.is_valid()
Out[6]: True

In [7]: serializer.validated_data
Out[7]: 
OrderedDict([('brand', {'uuid': UUID('1b03c6e1-8d9c-4273-ad07-d0d59a7f8cd9')})])

In [8]: serializer.validated_data['brand'] 
Out[8]: {'uuid': UUID('1b03c6e1-8d9c-4273-ad07-d0d59a7f8cd9')}
```

So here is the issue: in one way (deserialization), `brand` is the UUID of the Brand instance, as expected in its declaration in `ProductSerializer`. 
In the other way (serialization), `brand` points to a dictionary with a key called 'uuid' to refer to the UUID of the brand. As if DRF is managing a nested relationship, but still using the `brand` field declaration to restrict the data to the `uuid` field of the Brand model.

Why isn't the behaviour symmetric ? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you be more specific. What are you actually looking for?

Comment: You have `uuid` in product, but you replaced that with the brand `uuid` in the `serializer`. So it always returns brand `uuid` instead of product.

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. serializer.validated_data['brand'] is a value while ProductSerializer(product)['brand'] is a *field*. Try ProductSerializer(product).data['brand'] instead

Comment: Linovia makes a good point. 
Just to mitigate whether brand is a UUIDField or a UUID: 

    `In [6]: serializer.data['brand'] `
    `Out[6]: '1b03c6e1-8d9c-4273-ad07-d0d59a7f8cd9'`